# How to manually create a SocialApp with django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

What I want to achieve:

- create a user
- create a SocialApp with facebook as provider
- create a SocialAccount with the previously created user and social app

Comment: Saving a social app to the database? I dont understand what do you mean. What do you want to save to the database?

Comment: I've managed to do this with LinkedIn instead of FB. Have you followed a tutorial? Is there a particular step you're stuck on?

Comment: I've actually found SocialApp and SocialAccount under allauth.socialaccount.model, trying it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your desire provider you need to consider that the provider field from **SocialApp** and **SocialAccount** is a **CharField** with **choices** set to `allauth.socialaccount.providers.registry.as_choices()` which is a generator that yields tuples such as `('facebook', 'Facebook')`, so we are basically interested in using **'facebook'** for the **provider** field.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp, SocialAccount

user = User(...)
user.save()

sapp = SocialApp(provider='facebook', name='MyApp', 
    client_id='<your facebook app client id>',
    secret='<your facebook app secret key>')

sapp.save()
sapp.sites.add(1) // or your site id

sacc = SocialAccount(uid="<your facebook uid>",
    user=user, provider='facebook')

sacc.save()
```